# Subscriptions : numberOfSeats : needed for Vault and Drive storage

Tags: google-reseller-api

The API tells us the number of seats for skuId "Google-Apps-For-Business" but for skuIds "Google-Vault" and "Google-Drive-storage-??TB" it's blank.

We need this data to match all licenses with our billing system.